# Auto create Jenkins jobs for branches and pull request via declarative code in scm

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, gitlab, bitbucket

I am looking to auto create jobs in jenkins upon pull request , branches, master push etc similar to what we do in Gitlab. My SCM is butbucket here.

I have so far setup docker based agent integration with Jenkins and butbucket, when I create a job and configure it to use repo it all works fine , but I just want to remove altogether a step of job creation in jenkins and want the workflow like this:

In butbucket source code repo to keep all pipeline configuration for and branch and tag to trigger Jenkins pipeline without touching Jenkins for job creation or any config creation. Just want to drive all via the script in code repo for pipeline .

Any recommendations or help for workflow would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Bitbucket Branch Source plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/cloudbees-bitbucket-branch-source/), which is an official plugin developed by the Jenkins developers.  This plugin automatically creates jobs for all branches and pull requests of all repos in a project, and if you use Bitbucket Cloud it will also set up webhooks in Bitbucket to ensure pushes and PR updates automatically trigger builds in Jenkins.

Comment: This didn't work properly for me even though I have configured jenkins to use this bitbucket server.